# How to initialize web app using Firebase 9? React native and Expo

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo

I'm trying to initialize the app but I get `can't find variable firebase`, I'm still learning and it's hard to understand firebase. I'm using the latest SDK version

here's how I'm doing that

```js
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';

const firebaseConfig = {
  /// config
};

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}

import { getFirestore, collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore';
const db = getFirestore();
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
```

Comment: Not sure but you might need to 
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
if you want to check if the app already exists, hence "firebase.apps.length"

Comment: Gives me ``` firebase/compat/app couldn't be found within project ```

Comment: Did you install with npm i firebase@9.0.2?

Comment: No, Expo install firebase

Comment: Ahh ok so thats the issue, expo doesnt yet fully support v9, you can manually install it but if you run it through expo it should install v8,
Thats for expo sdk 42, 43 is supposed to come out this month according to rumors and then it might change

Comment: Ok so should I install v8 instead of v9?

Comment: Up to you, you can work with V9 if its a big project and it will save some downloading unneccesery content, if its a small project for you justgo with 8 imo